# Experiencing odd behavior with bitshifting/masking

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

*Backstory: I'm working on a toy compiler that takes some simplified assembly-like text and converts it into 32-bit instructions.*

The conversion into 32-bit instructions is working correctly, but when I try to output the results, I run into some issues. Specifically, the macros I wrote to pull out the various segments seem to be mangling values in ways I can't explain.

The following loop is where I run into issues (bit manipulations are stored in macros, but I expanded them out for simpler debugging):

```
while(pc < num_insts)
{
   printf("full: %x | op: %x | rs: %x | rt: %x | rd: %x | imm: %x\n",
      inst_mem[pc],
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 26) & 0x0000003F),
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 21) & 0x0000003F),
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 16) & 0x0000003F),
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 11) & 0x0000F800),
      (inst_mem[pc++] & 0x0000FFFF));
}
```

Which prints out the following:

```
full: 20450008 | op: 8 | rs: 2 | rt: 5 | rd: 0 | imm: 10
full: 0 | op: 0 | rs: 0 | rt: 0 | rd: 0 | imm: 8
```

The correct values for those lines would be:

```
full: 20450008 | op: 8 | rs: 1 | rt: 4 | rd: 0 | imm: 16
full: 20240010 | op: 8 | rs: 2 | rt: 5 | rd: 0 | imm: 8
```

If I replace that with the simpler

```
while(pc < num_insts)
{
   printf("full: %x", inst_mem[pc++]);
}
```

then each full address is output as I would expect. This implies to me that the parsing is all working as it should, and that my macros to pull values out of the address after parsing and jacking with something they shouldn't be. I'm just not sure what that *something* would be.

Since `inst_mem[]` contains `int32_t` values and all shifts are less than 32, it shouldn't be an issue of undocumented shift behavior.

If anyone can provide a nudge in the right directions, I would be more than grateful. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: You have undefined behavior in your code, with the `pc++` operation. You don't know in which order the arguments will be evaluated, so the `pc++` may be evaluated first, last or in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of evalutation of function arguments doesn't have to be "first argument first". Therefore, it is very dangerous to have increments like `pc++` when other function arguments use `pc`. Change `pc++` to `pc` and increment `pc` afterwards:

```
while(pc < num_insts)
{
   printf("full: %x | op: %x | rs: %x | rt: %x | rd: %x | imm: %x\n",
      inst_mem[pc],
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 26) & 0x0000003F),
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 21) & 0x0000003F),
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 16) & 0x0000003F),
      ((inst_mem[pc] >> 11) & 0x0000F800),
      (inst_mem[pc] & 0x0000FFFF));
   pc++;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Did not realize order of evaluation was undocumented in this case. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the program is both [unspecified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) and [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified if we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.2.2` *Function calls* paragraph *10* is says(*emphasis mine*):

> The **order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and
>   subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified**, but there is a sequence point
>   before the actual call.

So we can not determine when the sub-expression `inst_mem[pc++] & 0x0000FFFF` will be executed with respect to the other arguments and so we don't know when `pc` will be incremented.

It is *undefined behavior* because if we look at section `6.5` *Expressions* paragraph *2* says(*emphasis mine*):

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.72) **Furthermore, the prior value
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored**.73)

and in footnote *73* provides the following examples of *undefined behavior*:

```
i = ++i + 1;
a[i++] = i;
```

So within a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) if an object is modified the previous value can only be read to determine the value to be stored. In your code `pc` is being modified with the `pc++` expression and is being read several other times to determine array indexes and thus invokes undefined behavior.

The fix is straight forward and that is to move the `pc++` out of the `printf` call.